# How do I replace a line in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in Python for an assessment where I have to update a stock file for a shop.

[My instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OV0L.jpg)

My code so far:

```python
#open a file in read mode
file = open("data.txt","r")
#read each line of data to a vairble
FileData = file.readlines()
#close the file
file.close()

total = 0 #create the vairble total
AnotherItem = "y" # create
while AnotherItem == "y" or AnotherItem  == "Y" or  AnotherItem ==  "yes" or  AnotherItem ==  "Yes" or  AnotherItem ==  "YES":
        print("please enter the barcode")
        UsersItem=input()
        for line in  FileData:
                #split the line in to first and second section
                barcode = line.split(":")[0]
                item = line.split(":")[1]
                price = line.split(":")[2]
                stock = line.split(":")[3]

                if barcode==UsersItem:
                    file = open("data.txt","r")
                    #read each line of data to a vairble
                    FileData = file.readlines()
                    #close the file
                    file.close()
                    print(item +"       £" + str(float(price)/100) + "      Stock: " + str(stock))
                    print("how many do you want to buy")
                    HowMany= input()
                    total+=float(price) * float( HowMany)
                    file = open("data.txt","a")
                    StockLevel=float(stock)
                    file.write(item + ":" + price + ":" +str(float((StockLevel-float(HowMany)))))
                    file.close()
                    print("Do you want to buy another item? [Yes/No]")
                    AnotherItem = input()
        if AnotherItem == "n" or "N" or "no" or "No" or "NO":
                print("total price: £"+ str(total/100))
```

When I try to update my stock file it writes to end of the data file, instead of over the line I want it to.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but `if AnotherItem == "n" or "N" or "no" or "No" or "NO":` is going to prove problematic also (and make you go "no no no no no no!"), as it will always run, because even if `AnotherItem == "n"` would yield `False`, `... or "N"` will yield a truthy value, e.g. non-empty string. You want `if AnotherItem in {"n", "N", "no", "No", "NO"}:`, for example.

Comment: That's because you opened the file for append.  If this is a text file then you can only overwrite characters of the same length, it does not have "records" as such.  You will need to write the lines to a new file, replace the line/s you need to, then rename the file.

Comment: @cdarke How would i rename a file?

Comment: @Lightningz1 `os.rename`, consult the Python doc for the `os` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open("data.txt", "a")
```

Opens the file in append mode, means writing to the end of the file without overwriting data (adding to it, not changing).

Use

```
file = open("data.txt", "w")
```

Instead, to flush the file contents and overwrite them.

---

If you have some lines, and you only want to change the last do as follows:

```
data = open("data.txt").read().split("\n")
```

get an array of the file lines.

```
data[-1] = new_line_contents
```

change the last line to the new content.

```
open("data.txt", "w").write("\n".join(data))
```

write back with flushing the new data (join the elements in data with newline between them)